# Reflection on IQueryable OfType<>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, reflection

I have a Employees DbSet in my Entity Framework context that can be queried as:

```
IQueryable employees = _context.Employees;
```

The Idea is to execute the below method using Reflection:

```
var result= _context.Employees.OfType<PaidEmployee>()
```

I have extended the Employee object to create an PaidEmployee class.
I want to query the context for PaidEmployee using REFLECTION.

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom("MyModel.dll");
Type t = asm.GetType("PaidEmployee");

var ofType = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("OfType",
                     BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

var methodinfo = ofType.MakeGenericMethod(t);

var obj = methodinfo.Invoke(employees , null);
```

When I execute the above code, it gives me the error:

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException was unhandled by user
>   code   HResult=-2147352562   Message=Parameter count mismatch.
>   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture)
>          at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
>          at Tests.test_dynamic.TestMethod2() in e:\Projects\Tests\test_dynamic.cs:line 54   InnerException:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
var obj = methodinfo.Invoke(null, new[] { employees });
```

The `OfType` is static, so `null` `obj` (the first parameter of `Invoke`, that is the instance of the object to use for the method)!