# Reflection on IQueryable FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I have a Employees DbSet in my Entity Framework context that can be queried as:

```
IQueryable employees = _context.Employees;
```

The Idea is to execute the below method using Reflection:

```
var result= _context.Employees.FirstOrDefault()
```

I want to query the context for FirstOrDefault using REFLECTION.

```
var firstordefault = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("FirstOrDefault", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

When I execute the above code, it gives me the error:

**Ambiguous match found**

> System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2147475171   Message=Ambiguous match found.   Source=mscorlib
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.RuntimeType.GetMethodImpl(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, CallingConventions callConv, Type[] types,
>   ParameterModifier[] modifiers)
>          at System.Type.GetMethod(String name, BindingFlags bindingAttr)
>          at Tests.test_dynamic.TestMethod2() in e:\Projects\Tests\test_dynamic.cs:line 70   InnerException:

How can I resolve the ambiguity of this method.

Comment: `FirstOrDefault` has two overloads.  You need to pass parameter types.  With generics, this is tricky.

Comment: calling the method as:  var firstordefault = typeof(Queryable).GetMethod("FirstOrDefault", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public,null,new Type[] { typeof(Queryable) },null);  also didn't work. It returned null

Comment: why you need this? try to explain what's behind this requirement...

Comment: Its an extension for my previous post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775756/reflection-on-iqueryable-oftype    where I will know the object only during runtime

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338033/how-to-use-getmethod-for-static-extension-method +  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035719/getmethod-for-generic-method

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this ambiguity, you can use a Linq query as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897657/passing-the-correct-type-parameter-to-methodinfo-getmethod#28897868):

```
MethodInfo mi = typeof(Queryable)
    .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
    .First(x => x.Name == "FirstOrDefault" &&
                x.GetParameters().Length == 1 &&
                x.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQueryable<>));
```